# Angular: Testing apis from component

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have started learning how to test angular projects. So far basic unit testing is working fine for me but for the dependency testing especially when API services are injected into the component I am facing issue for providing `HttpClient`. I have tried different solutions but none is working for me.

**Service**

```
// Present in HttpClientService file
getDisposition() {
  return this.http.get<{ message: string, data: { dispositionList: Disposition[] } }>(`${this.URL}/disposition/get`);
}

// Present in FileProcessService file
deleteMedia(media: string) {
    return this.http.delete<{ message: string }>(`${this.URL}/certificate/delete?certificate=${media}`);
}
```

**add-edit-activity.component.ts**

```
import { HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AssignedPerson } from '@model/assigned-person.model';
import { Disposition } from '@model/disposition.model';
import { mimeTypes } from '@model/mime-type';
import { FileProcessService } from '@service/file-process.service';
import { HttpClientService } from '@service/http-client.service';
import { DeleteComponent } from '@shared/delete/delete.component';
import { CustomErrorStateMatcher } from '@validator/error-state-matcher';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-activity',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-activity.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-activity.component.css']
})
export class AddEditActivityComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddEditActivityComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private _http: HttpClientService, private _fileService: FileProcessService, private toastr: ToastrService, private dialog: MatDialog,) { }

  re = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z-]*/, 'g');
  ISOstamp = { T: ' ', Z: '000' };
  matcher = new CustomErrorStateMatcher();
  dispositionList: Disposition[] = [];
  assignedPersonList: AssignedPerson[] = [];
  filterAssignedPersonList: AssignedPerson[] = [];
  uploaded = false;
  uploadProgress = false;
  fileURL: SafeUrl;
  activityForm = this.fb.group({
    gaugeId: [this.data.gaugeId, Validators.maxLength(9)], createTimeStamp: [{ value: new Date().toISOString().replace(/[TZ]/g, m => this.ISOstamp[m]), disabled: true }],
    user: [{ value: sessionStorage.getItem('username'), disabled: true }], disposition: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]],
    assignedPersonName: ['', Validators.maxLength(30)], department: ['', Validators.maxLength(20)],
    shift: ['', Validators.maxLength(1)], remark: ['', Validators.maxLength(50)],
    calibrationDate: ['', Validators.maxLength(10)], attachment: ['', Validators.maxLength(255)]
  });

  @ViewChild('file') certificate: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data.type.match(this.re)[0] === 'Update' && this.setFormValues();
    this._http.getDisposition().subscribe(response => this.dispositionList = response.data.dispositionList);
    this._http.getAssignedPerson().subscribe(response => this.assignedPersonList = this.filterAssignedPersonList = response.data.assignedToList);
  }

  get GaugeId() {
    return this.activityForm.get('gaugeId');
  }

  get TimeStamp() {
    return this.activityForm.get('createTimeStamp');
  }

  get Attachment() {
    return this.activityForm.get('attachment');
  }

  get Disposition() {
    return this.activityForm.get('disposition');
  }

  get DispositionValue() {
    return this.dispositionList.map(e => e.dispositionType).indexOf(this.Disposition.value) < 0;
  }

  get AssignedTo() {
    return this.activityForm.get('assignedPersonName');
  }

  get AssignedToValue() {
    return this.assignedPersonList.map(e => `${e.firstName} ${e.lastName}`).indexOf(this.Disposition.value) < 0;
  }

  private async setFormValues() {
    this.activityForm.patchValue({ ...this.data });
    if (this.data.attachment) {
      this.uploadProgress = true;
      this.uploaded = true;
      await this.fetchUploadedFile(this.data.attachment, mimeTypes[this.data.attachment.split('.')[1]]);
      this.activityForm.markAsPristine();
    }
  }

  searchAssignedPerson(event) {
    if (event.target.value) {
      this.filterAssignedPersonList = [];
      for (let person of this.assignedPersonList) {
        if (person.firstName.toLowerCase().startsWith(event.target.value.toLowerCase())) {
          this.filterAssignedPersonList.push(person);
        }
      }
    } else { this.filterAssignedPersonList = this.assignedPersonList }
  }

  upload(event) {
    const file: File = event.target.files[0];
    this.certificate.nativeElement.value = '';
    if (file.size > (20 * 1000 * 1000)) { // Checking if File size is above 20MB
      this.toastr.error('Size of ' + file.name + ' is above 20MB');
      return;
    }
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('certificate', file, file.name);
    this.processAttachment(fd);
  }

  private processAttachment(file: FormData) {
    this._fileService.uploadMedia(file).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) { this.uploadProgress = true }
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        let media = event.body.data.Certificate;
        this.fetchUploadedFile(media.fileName, media.fileType);
        this.toastr.info(event.body.message);
      }
    }, error => {
      this.toastr.error(error.error.message);
      this.uploadProgress = false;
    });
  }

  private async fetchUploadedFile(file: string, mimeType: string) {
    try {
      let response = await this._fileService.getMedia(file).toPromise();
      this.fileURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response], { type: mimeType })));
      this.uploaded = true;
      this.uploadProgress = false;
      this.activityForm.patchValue({ attachment: file });
      this.Attachment.markAsDirty();
    } catch (error) {
      this.uploadProgress = false;
      this._fileService.processError(error.error)
    }
  }

  deleteFile() {
    this.dialog.open(DeleteComponent, {
      width: '350px', disableClose: true
    }).afterClosed().subscribe(response => {
      if (response) {
        this._fileService.deleteMedia(this.Attachment.value).subscribe(response => {
          this.toastr.info(response.message);
          this.activityForm.patchValue({ attachment: '' });
          this.Attachment.markAsDirty();
          this.uploaded = false;
        }, error => this.toastr.error(error.error.message));
      }
    });
  }

  async doAction() {
    let message = '';
    if (this.data.type.match(this.re)[0] === 'Add') {
      message = await (await this._http.addActivityLog(this.activityForm.getRawValue()).toPromise()).message;
    } else {
      message = await (await this._http.updateActivityLog(this.GaugeId.value, this.TimeStamp.value, this.activityForm.getRawValue()).toPromise()).message;
    }
    this.dialogRef.close(message);
  }
}
```

**add-edit-activity.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FileProcessService } from '@service/file-process.service';
import { HttpClientService } from '@service/http-client.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AddEditActivityComponent } from './add-edit-activity.component';

describe('AddEditActivityComponent', () => {
  let component: AddEditActivityComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddEditActivityComponent>;
  let _http: HttpClientService, _file: FileProcessService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AddEditActivityComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: { type: 'Add Activity Log', gaugeId: 'W-001' } },,
        { provider: HttpClientService, useValue: null },
        { provider: FileProcessService, useValue: null }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddEditActivityComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    _http = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(HttpClientService);
    _file = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FileProcessService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
  // These 2 tests throwing error.
  it('SHOULD mock http service', () => {
    let spy = spyOn(_http, 'getDisposition').and.callFake(() => {
      return of({
        message: '',
        data: { dispositionList: [] }
      }).pipe(delay(100));
    });
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick(100);
    expect(component.dispositionList).toEqual([]);
  });

  it('SHOULD mock file service', () => {
    let spy = spyOn(_file, 'deleteMedia').and.callFake((file: string) => {
      return of({ message: '' }).pipe(delay(100));
    });
    component.deleteFile();
    tick(100);
    expect(component.uploaded).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

The error that am getting for those 2 tests (I'm providing the error of 1 test case, the same is coming for the 2nd one also):

> 1. SHOULD mock http service
>    AddEditActivityComponent
>    Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [..., ..., ...,
>    ..., ?undefined?, ..., ...]
>    at throwInvalidProviderError (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:240:1)
>    at providerToFactory (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11550:1)
>    at providerToRecord (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11521:1)
>    at R3Injector.processProvider (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11424:1)
>    Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for getDisposition() Usage: spyOn(, ) Error:  :
>    could not find an object to spy upon for getDisposition() Usage:
>    spyOn(, )
>    at

Anyone, please help what's the exact error happening with my test cases? Stuck here for almost 2 days.

Comment: I'm just guessing here but you're providing `HttpClientService` and `FileProcessService` as `null`. And the error message seems quite clear to me: "could not find an object to spy upon for getDisposition()" There is nothing to spy on in a null value.

Comment: @lbsn how can I pass the function from the provider? I've tried removing the service from provider as I am already injecting from the ```beforeEach``` but that gives error

Comment: Not a jasmine expert here, but I guess you should at least provide a definition for the function you'd like to spy on. Something like: `provider: HttpClientService, useValue: {getDisposition: () => {}}`

Comment: let me check it

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid using a 'null' value when providing services in the TestBed, that what is causing your problem.

The best way to mock Angular services is to create SpyObj instances and then use them like what is done [Angular tests documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#angular-testbed).

Here is how would be your spec file if you were using SpyObj:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FileProcessService } from '@service/file-process.service';
import { HttpClientService } from '@service/http-client.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AddEditActivityComponent } from './add-edit-activity.component';

describe('AddEditActivityComponent', () => {
  let component: AddEditActivityComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddEditActivityComponent>;
  let httpSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<HttpClientService>;
  let fileSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<FileProcessService>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AddEditActivityComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: { type: 'Add Activity Log', gaugeId: 'W-001' } },
        {
          provider: HttpClientService,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClientService', ['getDisposition', 'getAssignedPerson', 'addActivityLog', 'updateActivityLog'])
        },
        {
          provider: FileProcessService,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('FileProcessService', ['uploadMedia', 'getMedia', 'deleteMedia', 'processError'])
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddEditActivityComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    httpSpy = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(HttpClientService) as jasmine.SpyObj<HttpClientService>;
    fileSpy = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FileProcessService) as jasmine.SpyObj<FileProcessService>;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
  // These 2 tests throwing error.
  it('SHOULD mock http service', () => {
    httpSpy.getDisposition.and.callFake(() => {
      return of({
        message: '',
        data: { dispositionList: [] }
      }).pipe(delay(100));
    });
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick(100);
    expect(component.dispositionList).toEqual([]);
  });

  it('SHOULD mock file service', () => {
    fileSpy.deleteMedia.and.callFake((file: string) => {
      return of({ message: '' }).pipe(delay(100));
    });
    component.deleteFile();
    tick(100);
    expect(component.uploaded).toBe(false);
  });
});
```